# how to get updated xml code of xml layout in Activity

Tags: android, xml, dynamic-programming

how to get all the change i made in Activity Class on button click in string format and save in text file or XML file.

i will give an example initially my layout has only one button with no background when i run code i change background image of my layout at run time now i need new changes i made at run time in XML format

Comment: Please add a bit more information, like the piece of code to get a better understanding of your issue.

Comment: i just want to get code of my xml file in string... i will give you an example initially my layout has only one button with no background when i run code i change background image of my layout now i need new changes i made at run time in XML format

Comment: It is still not clear why you need this. Once you inflate the layout, you can do what you want with the views. You can save the original values, change what you want in run time, revert the changes when you want. So why do you need the modified xml string?